# How can I get total physical memory using Windows cmd

Tags: windows, memory, cmd

I inquired typeperf counters and instances, but couldn't find anything about the total memory. I only found

```
    \Memory\Availble Bytes
    \Memory\Cache Bytes
    \Process\Private Bytes
    \Process\Working Set
```

and adding any combination of them didn't match the total memory in task manager.

I also tried

```
    systeminfo | findstr /C:"Total Physical Memory"
```

but this only worked in english mode(chcp 437). I am not an American and making program for various countries.. and above all, this takes too long time.

Please, anyone know good idea to get total memory in Windows with only cmd? Or please explain me the relation of memories so that I can calculate the total memory from typeperf queries..

Comment: `wmic path Win32_ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory/value` could be faster but truly I _do not know_ whether it's affected by OS locale. And yes, returned value is that from `systeminfo` multiplied by `1024×1024`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### How can I get total physical memory

Use the following command:

```
wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory
```

Example output:

```
TotalPhysicalMemory
4275273728
```

---

> **Total Physical Memory**
>
> ```
> wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory
> ```
>
> **Available Physical Memory**
>
> ```
> wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory
> ```
>
> **Virtual Memory Max Size**
>
> ```
> wmic OS get TotalVirtualMemorySize
> ```
>
> **Virtual Memory Available**
>
> ```
> wmic OS get FreeVirtualMemory
> ```
>
> ---
>
> You can combine them as follows into one command:
>
> ```
> wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory && wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVirtualMemorySize,FreeVirtualMemory
> ```

Source [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) answer [What's the equivalent command of “wmic memlogical” in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/a/334918/337631) by [8088](https://superuser.com/users/73637/8088)

Comment: if used separately the outputs are two lines each. the first line repeats the queried key whilst the second is a numeric value. getting only the numeric value is thus quite simple. example: `wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory | findstr [0..9]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
wmic memorychip get capacity
```

Answer (score 2):

Viktar's answer (`wmic memorychip get capacity`) gives you the capacity of each Dimm (which will work fine, if you have only one Dimm installed but gives you one value per Dimm if there is installed more than one). To get the size of total memory use:

```
wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory
```