# WMIC Command not displaying correct value?

Tags: batch-file, ram, audit, wmic

We use a product that reports back to our platform with audit information such as RAM and CPU.

However we are getting unusual results when it comes to the RAM.

The product uses the command: `wmic computersystem get totalphysicalmemory`

and the output value is 2.3GB RAM

However it has 4GB installed. We use this information to create Road Maps for our clients so needs to be accurate. Any idea why?

Comment: I have no idea why you use this information to create Road Maps for your clients! Futhermore, we cannot help you with your code if you do not include it within your question; please [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51283688/edit) accordingly.

Comment: The WMI result is returned in bytes, e.g. `4294967296`. Are you sure that it has output 2.3GB, or have you tried to perform some sort of math which hasn't worked as expected?

Comment: Please read, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic memorychip get capacity
```

Source : [How can I get total physical memory using Windows cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249830/how-can-i-get-total-physical-memory-using-windows-cmd/29250090)

With an Hybrid [batch-Vbscript] file you can do something like that :

```dos
@echo off
Mode 55,10 & color 0A
Title TotalPhysicalMemory ^& Memorychip Capacity
Set "WMIC_TOTMEM=wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory /format:Value"
Set "WMIC_Capacity=wmic memorychip get capacity /format:Value"
Set "CAP=Capacity"
Set "TOT=TotalPhysicalMemory"
Call :GetTOTMEM %TOT% TotalPhysicalMemory
Call :GetCapacityMem %CAP% Capacity
echo(
Call :Convert %TotalPhysicalMemory% TotalPhysicalMemory_Converted
Call :Convert %Capacity% Capacity_Converted
echo   -------------------------------------------------
echo     TotalPhysicalMemory = %TotalPhysicalMemory%
echo     Memorychip Capacity = %Capacity%
echo   -------------------Converted---------------------
echo     TotalPhysicalMemory = %TotalPhysicalMemory_Converted%
echo     Memorychip Capacity = %Capacity_Converted% 
echo   -------------------------------------------------
pause>nul & Exit
::-------------------------------------------------------
:GetCapacityMem
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  '%WMIC_Capacity% ^| find /I "%~1" 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::-------------------------------------------------------
:GetTOTMEM
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  '%WMIC_TOTMEM% ^| find /I "%~1" 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::-------------------------------------------------------
:Convert
Set "VBS=%Temp%\%Random%.vbs"
(
    echo wscript.echo Convert("%~1"^)
    echo 'Function to format a number into typical size scales
    echo Function Convert(iSize^)
    echo    aLabel = Array("bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"^)
    echo    For i = 0 to 4
    echo        If iSize ^> 1024 Then
    echo            iSize = iSize / 1024
    echo        Else
    echo            Exit For
    echo        End If
    echo    Next
    echo    Convert = Round(iSize,2^) ^& " " ^& aLabel(i^)
    echo End Function
)>"%VBS%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Cscript //NoLogo "%VBS%"') do ( set "%2=%%a" )
Del "%VBS%"
Exit /b
::-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @JamieEdwards Don't forget to accept it as answer if this helped you !

Comment: This returns a value per memory chip, so you have to add them up on your own (which is not so easy in `cmd` due to the 32-bit limitation)...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the number returned by `wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory` actually represents, but I recognised the resulting number is a bit less than summing up the numbers given by `wmic MemoryChip get Capacity`, which returns the size of every installed memory device.

Here is a pure batch script that determines the total memory capacity (see the explanatory comments), working around the restriction for numeric values of 32-bit signed integers:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem /* Retrieve total physical memory: */
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%I in ('wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory') do for /F %%J in ("%%I") do set "TOTMEM=%%J"
echo total physical memory = %TOTMEM%

rem /* Retrieve total memory capacity: */
set "GBYTESUM=" & set "BYTESUM="
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%I in ('wmic MemoryChip get Capacity') do for /F %%J in ("%%I") do (
    rem // Split huge number into two parts, Gigabyte and remaining Byte values:
    set "SIZE=%%J" & set "GBYTES=!SIZE:~,-9!" & set "SIZE=000000000%%J" & set "BYTES=!SIZE:~-9!"
    rem // Sum up Byte values, compensate for trailing zeros:
    set /A "BYTESUM+=1!BYTES!-1000000000"
    rem // Determine carry to be added to GigaByte values:
    set "CARRY=!BYTESUM:~,-9!" & set "CARRY+=0" & set "BYTESUM=!BYTESUM:~-9!"
    rem // Sum up Gigabyte values plus carry:
    set /A "GBYTESUM+=GBYTES+CARRY"
)
rem // Rejoin Gigabyte and Byte values into a huge number:
set "BYTESUM=000000000%BYTESUM%"
for /F "tokens=* delims=0 eol=0" %%Z in ("%GBYTESUM%%BYTESUM:~-9%") do set "TOTCAP=%%Z"
if not defined TOTCAP set "TOTCAP=0"
echo total memory capacity = %TOTCAP%

endlocal
exit /B
```